# How to convert date in to String MM/dd/yyyy Format?

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, date-formatting

I have a Date 2014-10-01 00:00:00.0
I have to convert into 10/01.2014
How can i?

Comment: Such "How can I" questions are more of "Give me the code" questions.  Look at the related questions on the right.  Good luck!

Comment: Why dont You search a little for solution? Here is something what will help You:
http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-date-and-calendar-examples/

Comment: rajesh, is your problem solved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

how about this one

```
try
 {
    String currentDate = "2014-10-01 00:00:00.0";
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
    Date tempDate=simpleDateFormat.parse(currentDate);
    SimpleDateFormat outputDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM.YYYY");           
    System.out.println("Output date is = "+outputDateFormat.format(tempDate));
  } catch (ParseException ex) 
  {
        System.out.println("Parse Exception");
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use SimpleDateFormat:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String date = sdf.format("Your date");
```

Answer (score 0):

try This

```
// Create an instance of SimpleDateFormat used for formatting 
  // the string representation of date (month/day/year)
  DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

 // Get the date today using Calendar object.
   Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();        
    // Using DateFormat format method we can create a string 
  // representation of a date with the defined format.
  String reportDate = df.format(today);

   // Print what date is today!
System.out.println("Report Date: " + reportDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy if you use the JodaTime library.

```
    DateTime dt = new DateTime();
    DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd.YYYY");
    String str = fmt.print(dt);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
Date d = sdf.parse("dd/MM.YYYY");
```